# How to change pageLength to 200

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery.dataTables.min.js (datatables.net) version 1.9.4.

I have tried this:

```
$('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable({
      "pageLength": 200
});
```

And I believe I have the ID right, from looking here:

[image]

It does nothing. My datatable still defaults to 10 records per page/view.

If the answer is that I need to upgrade, I took a peek at the latest, and there are a thousand different files. I couldn't find a single tidy js file that I can plug in, and have no idea which to use. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it should be `$('...').dataTable(...)` as JS is case sensitive.

Comment: My code snipped was straight off their website's docs.

Comment: Doesn't look like it: http://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

Comment: "_and there are a thousand different files_" - where? There is no difference in 1.10.x compared to 1.9.x, regarding the layout of the files.

Comment: David, if you download the latest and look in the zip, you'll see many js files.

Comment: @SweatCoder, there is only 3 files in `/media` - `jquery.dataTables.js`, the `min` version and a `jquery`. All the rest is plugins, that you dont need, and examples. No difference compared to 1.9.4 what so ever.

Comment: @SweatCoder, have deleted my answer. As I see in your comment, your problem is obviously that you initialize the datatable more than once. You are using dataTables wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) indicate that `pageLength` is available `Since: DataTables 1.10`

I was able to use iDisplayLength to achieve the desired result. I think that's also what you're looking for?

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/542/dynamically-change-idisplaylength